# How to kill waiting child processes in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kill-process

I have script as below

**testscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
  /sbin/tcpdump -n -c 2 -i eth0  >/tmp/pkt_eth0
  sleep 60
done
```

When I try to kill it `testscript.sh` vanish but `tcpdump` waiting process still there. Also for `testscript.sh` I am not able to use `killall` so need `pid`

```
$kill -15 pid
```

but would prefer

```
$killall -15 testscript.sh
```

to end script and all child processes. How it can be achieved?

Comment: If you ran the job in the background (append `&` to the command), and use the `wait` command to wait for completion, then you have much more control.  For example you can `kill` using the job-number rather than the PID.  You can trap signals (not SIGKILL) in the script using `trap`.

Comment: I used trap to add clean_up script but waiting process still can not be killed somehow

Answer (score 2):

If you set a minus sign before the process id, then the child processes are also killed. Test:

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  ./script2.sh 
  sleep 60
done
```

script2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1;i<=10;i++))
do
    echo "$i"
    sleep 10
done
```

After running the command with `./script.sh`, find the PID with `ps aux | grep script` (from a different terminal), and then kill it with:

```
kill -- -13859
```

Here 13859 is the PID of script.sh. After running `ps aux | grep script` you will see that both scripts have terminated.

Source: http://fibrevillage.com/sysadmin/237-ways-to-kill-parent-and-child-processes-in-one-command